# LED driver circuit with a resistor and a capacitor parallel with an LED in automotive dashboard

Tags: led, resistors, driver, automotive, parallel

I'm reversing engeering the dashboard of my motorbike (Yamaha T7 - 2019) and I found and a lot of circurity just to control the LED of a turn blinker.

I figure out this schematic:

[image: Schematic]

Why did they put a resistor and capacitor in parallel with the LED?

Comment: Thanks... The 5V comes from a regulator in the dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capacitor is for suppressing voltage spikes that could damage the LED (it forms a low-pass filter with R4).

My idea for the purpose of R3 is either to increase the current a bit for discontinuity detection or to reduce the voltage above the LED in failure situations or both.

Where do the +5 V come from? Thought there is everything 12 V on a bike.

Comment: Nice try, but I doubt about the danger for voltage spikes here. I would say, OP has a good question

Comment: Sure. C1 is a bit too small to let the LED switch smoother. Therefore the best it can do is to be a return path for high frequency noise and to suppress spikes. As far as I know the supply net in cars (and bikes) might be noisy. Let's put a scope there.

Comment: Modern dashboards are not the big clunky isolated circuits and lamps of the past. They have internal regulators and ics and cobs and leds.

Comment: But ignition and so on are still there as in old ages. I can't prove why it was placed there. But at the plave it sits it can do what I described should there be any noise or spikes. Feel free to give a better explanation.

Comment: Which component is more vulnerable for voltage spikes? The LED, or the transistor? I would say, the lead acid battery is a great protection against overvoltage, and for extra protection, I would put a capacitor between +5 and GND, not just over the led.

Comment: @Roland You are right. I'd also put a small cap to the base and likely a TVS from cathode to GND. But we are not asked to improve it (o:

Comment: thats why I made a comment, not an answer. But I answered on your speculation of voltage spikes